# Как вывести бинарное дерево в красивом виде?

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

У меня получилось бинарное дерево однобокое. 
Выводит все по одной стороне, не понимаю, как переписать функцию печати, дабы дерево выводилось в красивом виде по узлам (прикрепляю картинку +- того, что хотелось бы получить на выводе -- без графики, просто красивое 
 оформление текста на выходе)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
struct BinTree {
    int value;
    BinTree* left;
    BinTree* right;
};
//Функция для создания дерева
void newBinTree(int val, BinTree** Tree) {
    if ((*Tree) == NULL){
        (*Tree) = new BinTree; //Выделить память
        (*Tree)->value = val; 
        (*Tree)->left = (*Tree)->right = NULL;
        return;
    }
    if (val > (*Tree)->value) newBinTree(val, &(*Tree)->right);
    else newBinTree(val, &(*Tree)->left);
}
void Print(BinTree** Tree, int l){
    int i;
    if (*Tree != NULL){
        Print(&((**Tree).right), l + 1);
        
        for (i = 1; i <= l; i++) cout << "   "; {
            cout << (**Tree).value << endl;
        }
        Print(&((**Tree).left), l + 1);
    }
}

int NumberOfNodes(BinTree* Tree) { //Получаем количество элементов в дереве
    if (Tree == NULL) return 0;
    return NumberOfNodes(Tree->left) + 1 + NumberOfNodes(Tree->right);
}

void DestroyBTree(BinTree* Tree) { //Удаляем дерево для освобождения памяти
    if (Tree != NULL) {
        DestroyBTree(Tree->left);
        DestroyBTree(Tree->right);
        delete(Tree);
    }
}
void MenuProc() {
    BinTree* Tree = NULL;
    int val;
    int valSum = 0;
    while (_getch() != 27) {
        cout << "Введiть значення дерева: ";
        cin >> val;
        valSum += val;
        newBinTree(val, &Tree);
    }
    Print(&Tree, 0);
    cout << endl;
    int a = NumberOfNodes(Tree);
    cout << "Среднее арифметическое элементов в дереве-> ";
    cout << float(valSum) / a << endl;
    DestroyBTree(Tree);
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    MenuProc();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы хотите использовать графику для вывода или вывести такую структуру в консоли?

Comment: нет, без графики. Просто оформить текст узлов в консоли

Comment: тогда встает вопрос о размерах дерева: даже относительно небольшое дерево может просто не поместиться в вашей консоли. Но в любом случае отрисовка в консоли данного дерева будет выглядеть примерно так: считаете общее количество элементов в дереве и занимаемый ими размер в одной строке, а дальше идете от корня вниз и принтите ваше ноды начиная с середины строки (размер которой у вас уже должен быть) постепенно расширяясь влево и вправо

Comment: Мне хватит дерева из 7-8 узлов

Comment: в таком случае вышеописанный метод будет работать хорошо

Comment: Количество узлов я уже получаю a = NumberOfNodes(Tree), но не получается сообразить картинку как их печатать на экран

Comment: так я вам только что описал как это сделать. Что вам не понятно из того, что я написал?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802354/print-binary-tree-in-a-pretty-way-using-c

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Предлагаю также мой вариант, [смотрите мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222334/267338), я реализовал два компактных вывода в консоль. Первый вариант вывода ещё и занимает всего 5-6 строк кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только что для вас написал две функции (два варианта) для вывода дерева в консоль, первый вариант (функция dump0()) супер короткий и простой, но выводит немного в другом виде чем вы хотели, второй вариант довольно громоздкий (функция dump1()), но делает ровно то что вы хотели (даже наверное красивее), также сделал функцию dump2() она похожа на dump0() только выводит в порядке "правый, корень, левый", когда dump0() выводила "корень, левый, правый".

Также реализовал две версии - ASCII/UNICODE, в конце ответа вывод консоли вначале ASCII для всех dump()-ов, потом UNICODE для всех. Юникод вариант использует спец символы для рисования рамок/окон/таблиц взятые [с этой страницы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Drawing_(Unicode_block)). У кого СтэкОверфлоу не показывает юникод, то можете посмотреть пример вывода [на этой картинке в браузере](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpL1Q.png) или [на этой картинке в консоле](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njmUx.png).

Я ваш полный код не использовал, вместо этого скопировал только вашу BinTree структуру. Также у себя в коде не делал очистку ресурсов и памяти у BinTree, конечно в вашем коде вы должны очистку делать. Сами функции dump0/dump1 всё за собой чистят, т.е. для них доработок не нужно никаких.

Пример использования в функции main(), там создание дерева плюс вызов двух видов вывода в консоль.

Промотайте мой ответ в самый конец, там я вывел текст который был выдан в консоль обоими функциями.

Мой код полностью встроенный в ваш можно скачать [по ссылке тут](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1222314#main.cpp).

[Попробовать код ниже онлайн!](https://tio.run/##rRldb9vI8V2/YqOgAWlRn3GuV8lScHFyQADXV5yTtEAcEDS1tghTpLAkZftkAUWf76EPeeyvuz@SzswuyV2SspSiAmxx52vna2dmKX@16vqhF918@/Y8iPwwm3N2kqQiiG5mrRISxADj3lKHrbmfxkKHXGeRnwZx5IU61AtvYhGkC4M5zVYh1wFJOuf3Pl@lOnDJl7F4QMj1nF8z9@/vz1@OWgw@Jc1dEM3ju6S3ADIeJryCDmPfC7nERvPgutUCSzI/ZW@C6IPgnG2IIYhStvbCjE9oqZBHLOTXaQUkgpsFwLaTVus5aBVEnJ2dsw0DC8ZjP85SdnLCXPfs/fk718VnQsDm4YRtC5a3795Y93aV7fk9/m9PrTZ@IwEubdZG1la/zxZpukrG/T6PenfBbbDi88DrxeKmj6v@m/jefSs8cMmNa32MAj@ec/cKXHBrg9leGvhyOxlg5i/cRSzYlLW7bQdXa06rR7mag2xc9uVS5OvLSwnIKmvgzuU9dkuSHHZ52S3l5sB@ubObrEjcI1gLpj6p72U2ejUYtFn/6I@v/zzq68oTaiRR/1KoQnPEnUrc7wondORQyfy3QmY67ljivpb76eoMT3Wl/lPqZfiA5OiEX0vCeYVwYEj83bA0d5a0lilz2VEfsnIdB3M2z5argZUnuR9HScqOWAQJ4Zg@JcwLthKQl/coEgJyFcchE3GcwhpOC1eQ0EtyiK3OjZG9SgZmLjG/BmFszCzie234Yqx50KYst1A3oCKJaexK/QjandHRtIGr3bbNIyVP7zWznhH/46N66s7w6LIXL5ha0rG1baLHj@BpJqJJaYWsZyf5OZ@x9aYU5DBNylZyXYMdVhL8xt2UBeCXwQS@Tti6hzDLnrBOJyj3kwFZfw6@OLmjOs1@ajPWLh0EgbZth117UNsc2KDDhmw2LXaxoRJpIR99R8gFqqEi3oT39@DDAp9nQxEH23AvgvUgGD4Z6ShHKdUhJ5Qr7XQYwNxBk3oySu3zXNmRUM2pVIa9WVWZEGFNDQOWFfqGmkmVcB3vCBcdtwV4pDiAeopqwZjVorGL0LIPEOL/P4SIA4TsqjB4Zg2Tk4Un@NxdpUqGLq9B9mzGQmivCQiJsjAEtj25mT5ADwV1d1r16UISelkaw@LUQwU/f7E@XRQGQ@C11ZW9kcRYyL0JE70gSrhILdGDNCPje1f8JojkI8GgWEilmIBOX2YiesguLCK9lt4td6VXDC98upiBZ/cn8bGRxJhjjjTLogySIKhCny6sTRvPIPzbYulVgC1Wo10M6pzmXargU/B9vHRc9P0kbKsVQJka5BFbC0wCBzr3UPNZVyVClutkCcSUbNAwkLfHl6v0wbKxAeFSFlfWZyMszJYOgwIsEV14eLITaFyVZkD6d2erLFm4V55/a0mnENMSdJCHeYzCphLiK4iQfttoOWoNHdoKWou9te0Dau6xWXP1JBDfG5cn2MSuXBCVZBCHZ55KA/Wl50F5XjaFsXAsoR1MirUeqJACNel0Qp0DP9VhZ2Jg9VaI@5vYHamgAt6YDPkHDQiB1jqSZvUwI@y8z1d01DOJdab5BsTyOfwyaSaWNpHz6hRbhvenQmIb5/CafiDBZldwF7w1keDmXpnOKMMuCbatPe5B7p2@Mdo6fEGeNzTurdFYXxaN9YjajEM3POjRPsddlTepJ1DOtGpDIY@yJVzPTn/5eP4BWEaqLEsR4B5CEEjuh2KKE0VU0gFkMW6O5komWRyQxLDWsBOHBbmhDpWbUEGru0DXQ1b3XA3dM8PGkSNPr/x66v71p39Y9w57sKH6wTV0xqwHLI74PMZnu0L@/lwnP6mTl7X6V766SIXsok1zZeLkZdqPjNOM4YKODrf4aze1CHkCsTSSJV2I@E46RmRRGiy5y4WIhdWW247ZG28ur/rg4061Y5jisdi3n7W1TNb1FZN9aQ0yGvJZYPokk8pNJBe31WbZ/IWKbPT0zmTn5JM7Lf@ePTFa2jMIgi83ggcMxQvpHofBg//lqbGURoqN6ZGmwYkq0sQInpy/TGdI48vRhqykAlLkgTWwtUctGt/V@vHT76Maejf/E5zsZ1Ns6SSnWvfkIMcT3AEcY8xOdA92ECsMrKoBVGWryuY5vi5UvuHpyWBm4R47iUWdWNSIDYlDJRG6r6jDBcDDJNERo4JBNCH07fL@uUYybcSpEaCcdeHpGRvgZAPSx2Uwa0yCmITJJPYwhQFy4X5TuclaTW5UxqD4WgqCl@cudLEE/vshzhNNKpA0UUhD5mLo02QacJCHXrVQFan0AGiHdl383EsW5BqrVBhplVI4VoJYlNNVhoBcZCLXWMJgguh2SOGuoaaR8viq0TgO9PIxXOcPiXoQ@QN4Rj2InCYoiIonaYe2IH6jXVVadDH5apOCUQw0j8g3IrIoWTQNglblmwB4Urh8PFXqYM02pwc61rrfDNE6OxggdxDmFrS9oPAImvq110i14iINJNvy2Q0LDFgmgyrDBf8TW@N8unW9hb49Zj8HIknleHYnYmhAKN1hN3CJbuhkDXpQO3MYv19BuebzRq4GNe29fY6ORHHSnfL8qnGuMrvqTVRV1tLPEEMo9qICFYldH0bpbVtYGEei1ngN2kEqSlJBVaZGSiKSsBJ6yn6TrqZfQLmTCJOumu0k2iim29ZhndDKb6tFhCibEbCmJjalJva6xI/LR8hZpzEDjZGD2si60mrytqbanf2/vPo0asK6eXzHjxwps4h@64GUMtfvz3GOxUl66eHLk3xirf02hJ8Lnp5C94xD/kuWrrL09G/WD68Gg/zCXv5SRPrxVP5MZJ2duj@dncHNk0fux4vexw8/d39sFzz0@xGdVPGgpTT5LcVpacqM6Ef8Lv/ZaDMcOLULl45/5TTe2AwR0K2aqaqUI6Rkg20j8Xb/Tj8cvNOPjrH8s9qY/g7dffu0Z4Z/OcA1xcZ7SUdDU@XRoNDZAL/K4fs13k6aU709nU7ptT98t3fkvPxZALPH3iNluEfK8CApoz1SRgdJeblHysuDpBy7@MZnj6hjEqXKz16BYXx3oLzqeK7K70CVROZ7qb9g8oIqf5mGi1gxkvN7vamZyrzLqceMFOH3vbuFl1r2Dq3Uzt1h@SLj27f/Ag)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#else
    #include <locale.h>
#endif

struct BinTree {
    int value;
    BinTree* left;
    BinTree* right;
};

#define LN { std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl; }
#define DEB(x) { std::cout << #x << "=(" << (x) << ") "; }

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Drawing_(Unicode_block)
static std::string ch_hor = "-", ch_ver = "|", ch_ddia = "/", ch_rddia = "\\", ch_udia = "\\", ch_ver_hor = "|-", ch_udia_hor = "\\-", ch_ddia_hor = "/-", ch_ver_spa = "| ";
//static std::string ch_hor = "\u2500" /*─*/, ch_ver = "\u2502" /*│*/, ch_ddia = "\u250C" /*┌*/, ch_rddia = "\u2510" /*┐*/, ch_udia = "\u2514" /*└*/, ch_ver_hor = "\u251C\u2500" /*├─*/, ch_udia_hor = "\u2514\u2500" /*└─*/, ch_ddia_hor = "\u250C\u2500" /*┌─*/, ch_ver_spa = "\u2502 " /*│ */;

void dump0(BinTree const * node, std::string const & prefix = "", bool root = true, bool last = true) {
    std::cout << prefix << (root ? "" : (last ? ch_udia_hor : ch_ver_hor)) << (node ? std::to_string(node->value) : "") << std::endl;
    if (!node || (!node->left && !node->right))
        return;
    std::vector<BinTree*> v{node->left, node->right};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        dump0(v[i], prefix + (root ? "" : (last ? "  " : ch_ver_spa)), false, i + 1 >= v.size());
}

void dump2(BinTree const * node, std::string const & rpref = "", std::string const & cpref = "", std::string const & lpref = "") {
    if (!node) return;
    if (node->right)
        dump2(node->right, rpref + "  ", rpref + ch_ddia_hor, rpref + ch_ver_spa);
    std::cout << cpref << std::to_string(node->value) << std::endl;
    if (node->left)
        dump2(node->left, lpref + ch_ver_spa, lpref + ch_udia_hor, lpref + "  ");
}

void dump4(BinTree const * node, bool high = true, std::vector<std::string> const & lpref = std::vector<std::string>(), std::vector<std::string> const & cpref = std::vector<std::string>(), std::vector<std::string> const & rpref = std::vector<std::string>(), bool root = true, bool left = true, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> lines = nullptr) {
    if (!node) return;
    typedef std::vector<std::string> VS;
    auto VSCat = [](VS const & a, VS const & b){ auto r = a; r.insert(r.end(), b.begin(), b.end()); return r; };
    if (root) lines = std::make_shared<std::vector<VS>>();
    if (node->left)
        dump4(node->left, high, VSCat(lpref, high ? VS({" ", " "}) : VS({" "})), VSCat(lpref, high ? VS({ch_ddia, ch_ver}) : VS({ch_ddia})), VSCat(lpref, high ? VS({ch_hor, " "}) : VS({ch_hor})), false, true, lines);
    auto sval = std::to_string(node->value);
    size_t sm = left || sval.empty() ? sval.size() / 2 : ((sval.size() + 1) / 2 - 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sval.size(); ++i)
        lines->push_back(VSCat(i < sm ? lpref : i == sm ? cpref : rpref, {std::string(1, sval[i])}));
    if (node->right)
        dump4(node->right, high, VSCat(rpref, high ? VS({ch_hor, " "}) : VS({ch_hor})), VSCat(rpref, high ? VS({ch_rddia, ch_ver}) : VS({ch_rddia})), VSCat(rpref, high ? VS({" ", " "}) : VS({" "})), false, false, lines);
    if (root) {
        VS out;
        for (size_t l = 0;;++l) {
            bool last = true;
            std::string line;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < lines->size(); ++i)
                if (l < (*lines).at(i).size()) {
                    line += lines->at(i)[l];
                    last = false;
                } else line += " ";
            if (last) break;
            out.push_back(line);
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < out.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << out[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

void dump3(BinTree * root, int space = 0) {
   if (!root)
      return;
   enum { COUNT = 2 };
   space += COUNT;
   dump3(root->right, space);
   for (int i = COUNT; i < space; ++i)
      std::cout << "  ";
   std::cout << root->value << std::endl;
   dump3(root->left, space);
}

void dump1(BinTree const * node) {
    #define _MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
    #define _MIN(x, y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))

    auto RepStr = [](std::string const & s, size_t cnt) {
        if (ptrdiff_t(cnt) < 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("RepStr: Bad value " + std::to_string(ptrdiff_t(cnt)) + "!");
        std::string r;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
            r += s;
        return r;
    };
    std::function<std::tuple<std::vector<std::string>, size_t, size_t>(BinTree const * node, bool)> Rec;
    Rec = [&RepStr, &Rec](BinTree const * node, bool left){
        std::vector<std::string> lines;
        if (!node)
            return std::make_tuple(lines, size_t(0), size_t(0));
        auto sval = std::to_string(node->value);
        //if (sval.size() % 2 != 1) sval += " ";
        auto resl = Rec(node->left, true), resr = Rec(node->right, false);
        auto const & vl = std::get<0>(resl);
        auto const & vr = std::get<0>(resr);
        auto cl = std::get<1>(resl), cr = std::get<1>(resr), lss = std::get<2>(resl), rss = std::get<2>(resr);
        size_t lv = sval.size();
        size_t ls = vl.size() > 0 ? lss : size_t(0);
        size_t rs = vr.size() > 0 ? rss : size_t(0);
        size_t lis = ls == 0 ? lv / 2 : _MAX(int(lv / 2 + 1 - (ls - cl)), 0);
        size_t ris = rs == 0 ? (lv + 1) / 2 : _MAX(int((lv + 1) / 2 - cr), (lis > 0 ? 0 : 1));
        size_t dashls = (ls == 0 ? 0 : ls - cl - 1 + lis - lv / 2), dashrs = (rs == 0 ? 0 : cr + ris - (lv + 1) / 2);
        //DEB(node->value); DEB(lv); DEB(ls); DEB(rs); DEB(cl); DEB(cr); DEB(lis); DEB(ris); DEB(dashls); DEB(dashrs); std::cout << std::endl;
        lines.push_back(
            (ls == 0 ? "" : (RepStr(" ", cl) + ch_ddia + RepStr(ch_hor, dashls))) +
            sval + (rs == 0 ? "" : (RepStr(ch_hor, dashrs) + ch_rddia + RepStr(" ", rs - cr - 1)))
        );
        //if (lines.back().size() != ls + lis + ris + rs)
        //    throw std::runtime_error("Dump: First line wrong size, got " + std::to_string(lines.back().size()) + ", expected " + std::to_string(ls + lis + ris + rs));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _MAX(vl.size(), vr.size()); ++i) {
            std::string sl = RepStr(" ", ls), sr = RepStr(" ", rs);
            if (i < vl.size()) sl = vl[i];
            if (i < vr.size()) sr = vr[i];
            sl = sl + RepStr(" ", lis);
            sr = RepStr(" ", ris) + sr;
            lines.push_back(sl + sr);
        }
        return std::make_tuple(lines, (left || ls + lis == 0 || lv % 2 == 1) ? ls + lis : ls + lis - 1, ls + lis + ris + rs);
    };
    auto v = std::get<0>(Rec(node, true));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
        
    #undef _MAX
    #undef _MIN
}

int main() {
    #ifdef _WIN32
        SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    #else
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    #endif
    try {
        auto tree = 
            new BinTree{10,
                new BinTree{5,
                    new BinTree{1, 0,
                        new BinTree{2, 0, 0}
                    },
                    new BinTree{6, 0,
                        new BinTree{8, new BinTree{7, 0, 0}, 0},
                    },
                },
                new BinTree{19,
                    new BinTree{17, 0, 0},
                    new BinTree{21, new BinTree{20, 0, 0}, new BinTree{250, 0, 0}},
                },
            };
        std::cout << "===dump0===" << std::endl;
        dump0(tree);
        std::cout << "===dump1===" << std::endl;
        dump1(tree);
        std::cout << "===dump2===" << std::endl;
        dump2(tree);
        std::cout << "===dump3===" << std::endl;
        dump3(tree);
        std::cout << "===dump4_high===" << std::endl;
        dump4(tree, true);
        std::cout << "===dump4_low===" << std::endl;
        dump4(tree, false);
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
====== ASCII ======

===dump0===
10
|-5
| |-1
| | |-
| | \-2
| \-6
|   |-
|   \-8
|     |-7
|     \-
\-19
  |-17
  \-21
    |-20
    \-250
===dump1===
  /--10--\      
/-5\    /19-\   
1\ 6-\ 17  /21\ 
 2  /8    20 250
    7           
===dump2===
    /-250
  /-21
  | \-20
/-19
| \-17
10
|   /-8
|   | \-7
| /-6
\-5
  | /-2
  \-1
===dump3===
            250
        21
            20
    19
        17
10
            8
                7
        6
    5
            2
        1
===dump4_high===
  /---10--\
  |       |
/-5\     /19--\
|  |     |    |
1\ 6-\  17   /21-\
 |   |       |   |
 2  /8      20  250
    |
    7
===dump4_low===
  /---10--\
/-5\     /19--\
1\ 6-\  17   /21-\
 2  /8      20  250
    7

====== UNICODE ======

===dump0===
10
├─5
│ ├─1
│ │ ├─
│ │ └─2
│ └─6
│   ├─
│   └─8
│     ├─7
│     └─
└─19
  ├─17
  └─21
    ├─20
    └─250
===dump1===
  ┌──10──┐      
┌─5┐    ┌19─┐   
1┐ 6─┐ 17  ┌21┐ 
 2  ┌8    20 250
    7           
===dump2===
    ┌─250
  ┌─21
  │ └─20
┌─19
│ └─17
10
│   ┌─8
│   │ └─7
│ ┌─6
└─5
  │ ┌─2
  └─1
===dump4_high===
  ┌───10──┐
  │       │
┌─5┐     ┌19──┐
│  │     │    │
1┐ 6─┐  17   ┌21─┐
 │   │       │   │
 2  ┌8      20  250
    │
    7
===dump4_low===
  ┌───10──┐
┌─5┐     ┌19──┐
1┐ 6─┐  17   ┌21─┐
 2  ┌8      20  250
    7
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно чтобы данные были динамичными как у меня в примере. Вот бы в моем коде переписать функцию печати на что-то подобное.

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Это как раз не проблема. Всё уже готово у меня. Т.е. просто копируйте функцию либо dump0 либо dump1 (какая по выводу красивее выглядит для вас, первое дерево это dump0, второе dump1 в конце моего ответа). Так вот копируете чисто тело функции и всё к себе и вызываейте с вашим деревом. Ещё в начале файла #include строки надо скопировать тоже. Т.е. инклюд строки плюс чисто тело функции, больше ничего не надо.

Comment: с ошибками, dump1(tree)
Я пытаюсь вывести без try {...}, дабы данные узлов учитывались из клавиатуры, не были заданы константой

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Да это изза Windows.h, вообщем я поправил код и встроил в ваш, [вот ссылка](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1222314#main.cpp), по ссылке только исходник возьмите, т.к. по ссылке там линукс сервер то код до конца у них не скомпилируется, компилируйте на своей машине. Также я вызов Print() заменил на dump1() уже где надо. У меня дома на Windows ваш код скомпилировался с моим кодом (тот что по ссылке). Можете dump0 или dump1 использовать, оба встроил.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде работает..
Код очень огромный и сложно понять, но оно работает
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/print-binary-tree-in-2-dimensions-in-cplusplus 
В этом примере вывод боковой и очень мало кода который отвечает за печать дерева, но он вполне удовлетворяет вывод.. У меня трудность как скрестить мой код и печать

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Да по ссылке на tutorialspoint тоже хороший код, он по логике похож на мой dump0, т.е. подход тот же, потому и их и мой код простой, только порядком вывода отличается, у меня 1) корень 2) левый 3) правый. У них 1) левый 2) корень 3) правый. Так что их код для вас вполне может подойти тоже. Это уже вертикльный вариант dump1 сложнее сделать по логике. А вот в бок чтобы дерево росло оно очень просто делается.

Comment: Как их вывод скрестить с моим кодом ?) не хотелось бы трогать полностью дерево из-за печати

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Решил под их идею доработать мой dump0, в итоге получил dump2, пример его вывода я добавил в конец ответа моего. Также встроил dump2 в ваш код [по этой ссылке](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1222314#main.cpp).

Comment: /  | \  -- очень путают когда смотришь в консоль не сразу вникаешь что и куда ))
у них из-за пробелов наверное хорошо отображается

Comment: @AleXxxWEB По вашей просьбе встроил их вариант как dump3() в вашем коде по [этой ссылке](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1222314#main.cpp), если не понравится то вызывайте мой вариант dump2().

Comment: Можно высчитывать расстояние от края пробелом - дабы опустить / | \ на уровень ниже

Comment: Смотрится вполне себе прилично) Спасибо большое за помощь еще раз !)

Comment: @AleXxxWEB На самом деле если мои \ | / - символы плохо смотрятся, то если ваша консоль поддерживает Юникод символы, то можно использовать спец символы для рисования окон и таблиц, [они тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Drawing_(Unicode_block)), т.е. мои 4 символа заменить на такие:  │ ┌   └   ─    Получится вообще чёткие рамки. Но это если консоль юникодная, могу сделать если надо.

Comment: Было бы здорово, даже для своего развития, понять что и к чему)

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Всё, встроил юникод. Посмотрите конец моего ответа выше, там где вывод консоли, вначале идёт все дампы в ASCII варианте, потом все дампы в UNICODE. Посмотрите как выглядит. Также я добавил юникод вариант в ваш код [по этой ссылке](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1222314#main.cpp), для этого кроме добавления самих dump функций я ещё добавил в первых строках main() несколько строк для настройки юникод консоли. Ещё важный момент, обязательно сохраните `.cpp` файл ваш в UTF-8 формате, это важно для юникода.

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Если у вас юникод не показывается, то так для информации сообщаю, что я для таких случаев загрузил эту [картинку по ссылке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njmUx.png), чтобы можно было посмотреть как это выглядит.

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Чтобы переключить в вашем коде Ascii/Unicode версии досточно закоментировать или раскоментировать одну из строк где перечислены символы, они в строке начинающейся на `static std::string ch_hor = "`, там одна строка для аски другая для юникод, нужно оставить одну раскоментированной, а другую закоментированной, в зависимости от того какая нужна.

Comment: Все работает, вывод получился достаточно красивым с использованием UNICODE. 
Большое Вам спасибо за проделанную работу!)

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Супер! Рад был помочь :). Мне особенно понравилось что функции dump0, dump2 супер простые (несколько строк) и с уникодом вообще получились шикарными.

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Вообщем вдохновлённый идеей алгоритма из tutorialsport, я решил переписать функцию dump1 и сделал ей похожую dump4, функция стала в раза 1.5 короче и даже код проще (но всё ещё большая). Суть в том что dump4 это по сути тот же dump2 только с вращением полученного текста на 90 градусов и всё. Выглядит шикарно, по моему самый красивый из вариантов. Я встроил этот вариант в ваш код [по этой ссылке](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1222314#main.cpp), там я сделал два вызова `dump4(Tree)` и `dump4(Tree, false)` первый вариант рисует высокое дерево, второй низкое, выберете нужное.

Comment: @AleXxxWEB В консоле `dump4(Tree)` и `dump4(Tree, false)` выглядят как на картинке [здесь по ссылке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuFje.png). Почти идентичный вывод, первое просто выше второго, первое содержит дополнительную вертикальную черту `|` между уровнями дерева.

Comment: @AleXxxWEB Забыл сообщить, если консольный проект сделали с поддержкой Юникода и исходный `.cpp` файл в UTF-8 формате, то при компиляции в Visual Studio обязательно нужно в финальную командную строку `cl.exe` добавить флаг `/utf-8`. Возможно современная студия уже автоматически этот флаг добавляет, но если нет то там в настройках проекта есть возможность добавить дополнительные флаги командной строки, либо где то есть птичка "Поддержка UTF-8". Под Unix компиляторами CLang/GCC то же самое достигается добавлением двух флагов `-finput-charset=UTF-8 -fexec-charset=UTF-8`  .

Comment: Благодарю за помощь и подсказки. Получился действительно очень красивый вывод дерева)